# How to resolve Instagram force close for CM9

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-sl

I'm using CM9 (Alpha 14) adnroid 4.0.1  for my GTi9003. Every other app works fine except for instagram.

Picture doesnt load at picture editing/ picture filter screen (screenshot)  [image: Screenshot of the instagram]  and instgram hangs and I have to force close every time.
It was working fine on stock ROM. Any patches?

Answer (score 0):

i have cm10.2 nightly kernel and happens exactly the same. i read that some peolple with cm10.2 quarx didn´t have this trouble.
On the other hand I couldn't find any solution, so I'm thinking in testing cm9 (for motorola defy+) or go under cm7.

Comment: try the oldest version of instagram that is allowed on your device. Instagram 3.4 worked for me. The problem seems with HW composer.